# Endless flickering with Naru Meha?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

While looking at [this Possibility Storm puzzle](https://i.redd.it/14hww8jqa2v01.jpg) I wondered if it would be possible to do something along those lines:

1. Tap the mana dork for 1 colorless, making it 7 total mana.
2. Cast [Supernatural Stamina](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSupernatural%20Stamina%5d) on [Naru Meha, Master Wizard](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNaru%20Meha%2c%20Master%20Wizard%5d).
3. Cast [Illusionist's Stratagem](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIllusionist%27s%5d%2b%5bStratagem%5d) on one [Academy Journeymage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAcademy%20Journeymage%5d) and the Arcanist, and on top of it cast Vicious Offering, sacrificing Naru Meha as its kicker.
4. Naru Meha will return on the battlefield, its ETB will then copy Stratagem, the copy targeting Naru Meha again and the same Journeymage.
5. Journeymage's ETB bounces one of the opponent's creatures.
6. Repeat step 4 and 5, to end the loop use the same targets as in 3.
7. Attack with the unused 4/3 Journeymage.

Are these steps legal?

The puzzle, again:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you asking whether all of the steps you're describing are legal? Or whether that's the solution to the puzzle?

Comment: Whether this is legal, I'll clarify this in the question, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps are legal.  The only thing you need to remember is to let Supernatural Stamina resolve in step 2 before proceeding to step 3 (otherwise Naru Meha won't come back).  Also, when you get to step 6 and are repeating the loop, you need to go back to step 4 and use the targets there, not step 3.  Also note that in a tournament setting you would need to explicitly state where you are retaining priority to cast multiple things in a row.

Comment: Are you sure that steps 4 and 5 are loopable? I wouldve suspected that once Naru has returned the first time to copy the stratagem, the stratagem would resolve before bouncing her the second time and wouldn't be a valid target when she returned?

Comment: So your stack (bottom to top) Strat -> Viscious. Casting and kicking Viscious just puts it on the stack.  Then Stamina's trigger resolves, bringing back Naru.  Naru's ETB happens, copying Strategem. Stack now is Strat -> Viscious -> Strat (copy).  Let the top spell resolve.  Strategem flickers Naru and a Journeymage.  ETB triggers happen and you bounce an enemy creature and copy the bottom Strategem again.  Rinse repeat until the opponent is out of creatures.  Swing in with the untouched Journeymage for 4 damage for the win.

Comment: That is a crazy loop... almost game breaking essentially all you would need is Naru and stratagem for some cruel ETB triggers...

Comment: The trick is that Naru is getting flickered by the copy, the original spell stays on the stack for the whole loop without resolving once until you decide to stop.

Comment: @ThunderToes you need to find a way to flicker naru on the stack though, but I agree that it does look a bit too powerful for its cost

Comment: @ThunderToes I wouldn't say it's game-breaking. Sure it's an infinite loop, but that in itself is nothing new. This combo requires Naru and some ETB creature on the field, Stratagem and another instant flicker effect, so it's a 4-card combo really that also requires a lot of total mana and can be stopped anytime by instant creature control.

Comment: @Hackworth that makes more sense I thought it would just go infinite with Naru and Stratagem... I may still try and run this combo with say Temple of the Brood in commander.